# how to create postgresql database using sql file in django? please guide me step by step. I have sql as follows

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, pgadmin-4, django-3.0

here is sql code of file that i want to convert into postgresql database

```
CREATE TABLE banks (
        name character varying(49),
        id bigint NOT NULL
    );

--
-- Name: branches; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: siva; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE branches (
    ifsc character varying(11) NOT NULL,
    bank_id bigint,
    branch character varying(74),
    address character varying(195),
    city character varying(50),
    district character varying(50),
    state character varying(26)
);


--
-- Name: bank_branches; Type: VIEW; Schema: public; Owner: siva
--

CREATE VIEW bank_branches AS
 SELECT branches.ifsc,
    branches.bank_id,
    branches.branch,
    branches.address,
    branches.city,
    branches.district,
    branches.state,
    banks.name AS bank_name
   FROM (branches
     JOIN banks ON ((branches.bank_id = banks.id)));
```

then there is 120k lines of input by using stdin

```
COPY banks (name, id) FROM stdin;
COPY branches (ifsc, bank_id, branch, address, city, district, state) FROM stdin;
```

I use django3.2, psycopg2.8, postgrsql 13, windows10

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems did you encounter? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 'psql -h localhost -d bankdetails -U postgres -f "C:/Users/JAY SARDAR/Desktop/indian_banks.sql"'  i tried this. also tried to import as sql file but didnt work  @He3lixxx

Comment: when i tried to copy paste commands into pgadmin sql compiler i get ERROR: character with byte sequence 0x90 in encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"

Comment: UTF8 encoding is enabled, but i still recieve that error

Comment: tried importing csv file with this command that also didnt work 'copy public.bank from 'C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\Desktop\bankdetails.csv' DELIMITER ',' , csv HEADER;'      psql: error: could not translate host name "public.bank" to address: Unknown host

Comment: after converting code into ANSI and removing unwanted characters then converting back into UTF-8 in notepad++ it worked. with psql command

Comment: `psql -h localhost -d bankdetails -U postgres -f "C:/Users/JAY SARDAR/Desktop/indian_banks.sql `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ERROR: character with byte sequence 0x90 in encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"
```

for this error I converted file into ANSI and removed all ANSI characters which are not visible in UTF8 in notepad.

then run following command from psql shell

```
psql -h localhost -d databasename -U username -f "c://path_to_file.sql"
```